# Is There a way to convert to and from ICU MessageFormat and Gettext Po?

Tags: java, internationalization, gettext, messageformat

I have been looking for a converter but have come up empty. In the Javascript world, ICU's MessageFormat (with CLDR plural forms) seems to be winning the mind share.

But other platforms like iOS and Android have their own localization formats. Gettext's .po is an older format that can be converted to many of these formats and back

Is there a converter, in any language to convert from MessageFormat to Po and back?

Answer (score 0):

There is a project on github, [ICU2po](https://github.com/gunchleoc/ICU2po) that converts from ICU to po, but not back.

There's another project, [po2icu](https://github.com/LLK/po2icu), that can convert the other way.

I don't have experience with either project, so I'm not certain of their quality.